# Insert undefined variable in Laravel Eloquent get() query

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-api

I had two models in Laravel and I used Laravel for API.

```
Wallet = [name, wallet_category_id, user_id]
Wallet_Category = [id, name]
```

I call all wallet using get() in controller, how I can add wallet category name in my output ?

```
Wallet::where('user_id', $request->get('user_id'))->get()
```

the output will be like :

```
[
    {
        "id": 12,
        "user_id": 2,
        "name": "wallet1",
        "wallet_category_id" : 1,
        "created_at": "2020-03-09 22:40:29",
        "updated_at": "2020-03-09 22:40:29"
    },
    {
        "id": 13,
        "user_id": 2,
        "name": "wallet2",
        "wallet_category_id" : 2,
        "created_at": "2020-03-10 13:57:37",
        "updated_at": "2020-03-10 13:57:37"
    }
]
```

I want output like this :

```
[
    {
        "id": 12,
        "user_id": 2,
        "name": "wallet1",
        "wallet_category_id" : 1,
        "created_at": "2020-03-09 22:40:29",
        "updated_at": "2020-03-09 22:40:29",
        "category" : "cat_1"
    },
    {
        "id": 13,
        "user_id": 2,
        "name": "wallet2",
        "wallet_category_id" : 2,
        "created_at": "2020-03-10 13:57:37",
        "updated_at": "2020-03-10 13:57:37",
        "category" : "cat_2"
    }
]
```

is it possible?

thanks before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Relationship**

Make relationship in `Wallet` model

```
class Wallet extends Model
{

    public function walletcategory()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Wallet_Category','wallet_category_id','id');
    }
}
```

Now in controller

```
$wallets = Wallet::with('walletcategory')->where('user_id', $request->get('user_id'))->get();


foreach($wallets as $wallet){
    $wallet->walletcategory->name
}
```

**Join**

If you want to get it by using join then follow below query.

```
Wallet::select('wallet.*','wallet_category.name')->leftjoin('wallet_category','wallet_category.id','wallet.wallet_category_id')->where('wallet.user_id', $request->get('user_id'))->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use [Eagar Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) **Wallet Category** relation information while retrieving **Wallet**

Create the relation inside **Wallet Model**

```
//Wallet.php

...

use App\Wallet_Category;

...

public function walletCategory(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Wallet_Category, 'wallet_category_id', 'id')
}
```

Now retrieve necessary columns like id, name from relationship

```
$wallets = Wallet::with('walletCategory:id,name')->where('user_id', $request->get('user_id'))->get();
```

You will be able to retrieve walletCategory name like:

```
foreach($wallets as $wallet){
    //retrieve wallet category name like 
    $wallet->walletCategory->name
}
```